# JQuery Plugin Defaults and Options

Tags: jquery, default

How can I turn the following properties / variables in my plugin into defaults and options that can be set from document ready?

**// plugin js:**

```
(function($){
   $.fn.myPlugin = function(options){
      var myForm = this;
      myForm.variable1 = true;
      myForm.variable2 = true;
      myForm.variable3 = true;
      myForm.variable4 = true;

      ...

      if(myForm.variable1){
         // do something
      }

      ...
   }
})(jQuery);
```

**// document ready in page:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#form1').myPlugin();
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The simplest pattern is to extend a default options object. But it does mean that any parameters have to be passed together as an "option" object, eg: `myPlugin({variable2:false})`

```
(function($){
   $.fn.myPlugin = function(options){

      var defaults = {
          variable1 : true,
          variable2 : true,
          variable3 : true,
          variable4 : true
      }

      var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
      ...

      if(settings.variable1){
         // do something
      }

      ...
   }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: if you want this happen recursively in case you have nested options like ``defaults.foo.bar``, use ``true`` as the first parameter. eg: ``$.extend(true, {}, defaults, options)`` - hopefully this info saves some hours of others

Answer (score 0):

See following:

```
$('#form1').myPlugin({variable1 : true, variable2: false....});
```

and use

```
(function($){
   $.fn.myPlugin = function(options){

     options.variable1 = true;
          options.variable2 = true;
          options.variable3 = true;
          options.variable4 = true;
  }
})(jQuery);
```

For proper way see

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/01/how-to-set-default-settings-in-your.html