# Creating a jQuery plugin that initializes itself based on HTML class and name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins

I'm new to authoring jQuery plugins, but I've got a good bit of experience with using them.  Some plugins I've worked with can only be initialized programmatically, i.e.

```
$("input[name='blah']").fancyPants();
```

I find this annoying, but I've managed to figure out how to write a basic plugin like this from tutorials and looking through other plugins' code.

Others, like Bootstrap's modal component, can be initialized purely through markup, i.e.

```
<input type='text' name='blah' class='fancy-pants'>
```

And then just by including the plugin .js file, any input with class `fancy-pants` is automatically initialized as a `fancyPants` plugin.  I like this behavior, even though I know it hogs a particular class name.

**Question 1:** how do they do this?  I looked through `bootstrap.js`, but there seems to be a lot in there I don't understand.

**Question 2:**
Lets say I have a plugin that encompasses multiple elements in the DOM.  For example,

```
<button class="bootstrapradio" name="primary_group" value="epicurist"><i class='fa fa-cutlery'></i></button>
<button class="bootstrapradio" name="primary_group" value="futurist"><i class='fa fa-space-shuttle'></i></button>
<button class="bootstrapradio" name="primary_group" value="stoic"><i class='fa fa-tree'></i></button>        

<button class="bootstrapradio" name="beverage" value="beer"><i class='fa fa-beer'></i></button>
<button class="bootstrapradio" name="beverage" value="martini"><i class='fa fa-glass'></i></button>
```

**Without changing the markup structure** (e.g. adding a wrapper container), how can I automatically initialize two instances of my plugin, one which covers all buttons with a class of `bootstrapradio` and name `primary_group`, and another which covers all buttons with a class of `bootstrapradio` and name `beverage`?

EDIT: Here's what I'm working with right now.

```
(function ( $ ) {

    var methods = {
        init : function(options) {
            // Initialization method, adds classes to elements and binds events
            ...
            return this;
        },
        value : function( new_val ) {
            // Method to get/set value
            ...
        }
    };

    $.fn.bootstrapradio = function(methodOrOptions) {
        if ( methods[methodOrOptions] ) {
            return methods[ methodOrOptions ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof methodOrOptions === 'object' || ! methodOrOptions ) {
            // Default to "init"
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  methodOrOptions + ' does not exist on jQuery.bootstrapradio' );
        }    
    };    
}( jQuery ));
```

An example of how I'd like this plugin to transform the DOM:

BEFORE `document.ready`:

```
    <button class="bootstrapradio" name="primary_group" value="epicurist" title='Epicurist' disabled><i class='fa fa-cutlery'></i></button>
    <button class="bootstrapradio" name="primary_group" value="futurist" title='Futurist'><i class='fa fa-space-shuttle'></i></button>
    <button class="bootstrapradio" name="primary_group" value="stoic" title='Stoic'><i class='fa fa-tree'></i></button>        

    <button class="bootstrapradio" name="beverage" value="beer" title='Beer'><i class='fa fa-beer'></i></button>
    <button class="bootstrapradio" name="beverage" value="martini" title='Martini'><i class='fa fa-glass'></i></button>
```

AFTER `document.ready`:

```
    <button class="btn btn-xs bootstrapradio" name="primary_group" value="epicurist" title='Epicurist' disabled><i class='fa fa-cutlery'></i></button>
    <button class="btn btn-xs bootstrapradio" name="primary_group" value="futurist" title='Futurist'><i class='fa fa-space-shuttle'></i></button>
    <button class="btn btn-xs bootstrapradio" name="primary_group" value="stoic" title='Stoic'><i class='fa fa-tree'></i></button>
    <input type="hidden" name="primary_group">

    <button class="btn btn-xs bootstrapradio" name="beverage" value="beer" title='Beer'><i class='fa fa-beer'></i></button>
    <button class="btn btn-xs bootstrapradio" name="beverage" value="martini" title='Martini'><i class='fa fa-glass'></i></button>
    <input type="hidden" name="beverage">
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by initialise?

Comment: I think OP wants to know how to make use of say `data-role=modal` and similar attributes to trigger specific JS events. @ArtOfCode

Comment: Yeah, I get that, I just don't know what he wants to do in this initialisation.

Comment: Yes, I'd like the plugin to automatically call its `init` method on an element with a particular attribute (`class` or `data-*`, for instance).

Comment: If you're going this route you should also consider setting some defaults so the use can override those by passing in their own options. This is also very common pattern: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905507/jquery-plugin-defaults-and-options

Comment: Ok based on some answers here, I think I've figured it out.  I was going to put it up as a new project on Github...would it be inappropriate to link to that project from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, @ArtOfCode's answer put me on the right track.  Basically, I ended up using the `.each` pattern inside `$(document).ready`, and then check to see if the hidden `input` field has been added for the named group to which the element belongs.  So that way, I can add the `btn btn-xs` classes to all elements, but only add the hidden input once.

Then, I kept my original code with the `init` method to allow initializing the plugin programmatically.

Here's what I came up with, I'm releasing it under the MIT license :)

https://github.com/alexweissman/bootstrapradio

Answer (score 3):

You can select attributes with jQuery this way

```
$("[data-role='modal']");
```

So, in your example you'd have something like

```
$(".bootstrapradio[name='primary_group']").myPlugin();
$(".bootstrapradio[name='beverage']").myPlugin();
```

Lots of plugins do this without the class, by having a plugin specific attribute name.

One example is [Lightbox2](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/), which finds all of its possible elements using `$("[data-lightbox]")`, and then separates them into individual lightbox groups based on the value of those attributes.

If you want it to do it automatically, you would just wrap this same functionality in a document ready inside your plugin file.

As an example, for this HTML:

```
<div data-bootstrapradio='type1'></div>
<div data-bootstrapradio='type1'></div>
<div data-bootstrapradio='type2'></div>
```

And this Javascript:

```
$(function(){

    $.fn.bootstrapradio = function(params) {
        return $(this).each(function() {
            // Your code
        });
    }

    // Get all the radios on the page currently
    var $radios = $("[data-bootstrapradio]");

    // Get the groupings of them
    var radioTypes = [];
    $radios.each(function(i,el){
        var type = $(this).attr("data-bootstrapradio");
        if (radioTypes.indexOf(type) === -1){
            radioTypes.push(type);
        }
    });

    // Initialize the plugin using all radios of each type
    for (var i=0; i<radioTypes.length; i++){

        var type = radioTypes[i];

        var radioGroup = $radios.filter(function(i,el){
            return $(el).is("[data-bootstrapradio="+type+"]");
        }).bootstrapradio();

        // Do whatever else with radioGroup you want for initialization
    }

});
```

You end up with 2 bootstrapradios, the first which was initialized with two elements, and the second which was initialized with one.

Comment: Ok, but remember I want to structure it so that users don't need to write any additional JS to initialize the plugin.

Comment: Right, the document ready here is inside your plugin file, and will initialize your plugin on all those elements without the user doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

Well it does depend what you want to do in your initialisation. In general, I guess you're going to have to use a document-ready clause with some attribute checking logic and custom initialisation code.

Here's the standard construct for jQuery plugins:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(params) {
         return $(this).each(function() {
             // do your plugin stuff
         });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

I think you'll have to modify that so that on document-ready, your plugin initialises, and then perhaps if you still want to be able to call it, you add the function too:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".bootstrapradio").each(function() {
            if($(this).attr("name") == "primary-group") {
                // do something specific for name 'primary-group'
            }
            else if($(this).attr("name") == "something-else") {
                // do something else
            }
            else {
                // either catch-all or just drop the element
            }
        });
    });

    $.fn.myPlugin = function(params) {
        // do your plugin stuff
    }
})(jQuery);
```

If you want to use your existing `init` method and just give it the name, it's even easier:

```
(function($) {
    var self = this;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".bootstrapradio").each(function() {
            self.methods.init($(this).attr("name"));
        });
    });

    $.fn.myPlugin = function(params) {
        // do your plugin stuff
    }
})(jQuery);
```

The `self` is important to give you access to the correct scope here.

Additionally, your current code has a syntax error. Your last line:

```
}( jQuery ));
```

should be:

```
})(jQuery);
```

EDIT: Worth noting that that last point isn't actually a syntax error after all, according to the [article](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) linked in the comment below. Either works.

Comment: See http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/ at "Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)"

Comment: I think we're starting to get there, but what if I want it to act on any arbitrary `name`d elements?  I'm trying to figure out how to pass `$(this).attr("name")` into my `init` method.  Would that work?

Comment: It's easy to pass it in. What do you want to do with it? If you want to do different things with each different name you're stuck with if-else statements.

Comment: Well, basically I want to perform the same transform on each set of buttons (where the set is determined by a name).  Some of these transformations need to be applied to every element in the set, others should be performed only once per set.

Comment: We're getting close, but where do I put my `methods` now?  If I nest it just inside `(function($) {`, I get a console error (`self.methods` is undefined).

Answer (score 0):

Try (this pattern)

```
// hold jquery `ready` event until `plugin` "ready"
$.holdReady(true);
$(function() {
  // `deferred` until _after_ `plugin` defined ,
  // `ready` `hold` `resolved` within `plugin`
  $.bootstrapradio().css("font-size", "24px")
});

// `plugin` 
(function($, window, undefined) {
    // define `plugin` as `function` and `object`
    // check document for `bootstrapradio` `class` elements ,
    // if true , proceed , if not ,
    // create empty jquery object , proceed
    // define logic checks for elements , objects , other
    // in window , document , other
    $.fn.bootstrapradio = $.bootstrapradio = function(options) {
        $elems = $(".bootstrapradio").is("*") ? $(".bootstrapradio") : $({});
        // settings
        $.bootstrapradio.settings = {
            "primary_group" : "green"
            , "beverage" : "blue"
        };
        // extend settings to options
        var options = $.extend($.bootstrapradio.settings, options);
        // do stuff
        // e.g., apply `settings`/`options` to `$elem`
        // based on `name` , `value` attributes in `html`
        $elems.each(function(k, v) {
            $.each(options, function(_name, _value) {
                if (_name === v.name) {
                  $(v).html(v.value).css("color", _value)
                }
            })
        });
        // return `$elems`
        return $elems;
    } || {};
    // call `plugin`
    $.when($.bootstrapradio())
    .done(function(_$elem) {
        // check if `plugin` type cast
        // to both `function` and `object` ,
        // redundant check if `plugin` `in` window
        if (typeof $.fn.bootstrapradio === "function" 
           && typeof $.bootstrapradio === "object"
           && $.bootstrapradio in window) {
               // resolve jquery `ready` (`document.ready`) `hold` ,
               // do other stuff ,
               // e.g., `$.bootstrapradio().css("font-size", "24px")`
               $.holdReady(false);
        };
    })

}(jQuery, window));
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/f2asu701/